Issues with GDAL installation - ogr not available?
I am attempting to install GDAL on my Windows 10 machine. I have previously done this successfully using the wheels from Gohlke's now deprecated site so I am learning a new way to do an old thing. Source I used for installation steps: https://archive.ph/EXMXZ#selection-743.0-761.52
Steps I followed:

Install Python 3.10.0
Downloaded the wheels for GDAL, Pyproj, Fiona, Shapely matching the version of Python above from Gohlke's github (https://github.com/cgohlke/win_arm64-wheels)
Installed the wheels in this specific order: GDAL, pyproj, fiona, shapely

I went to verify the install, and I see the message below.
C:\Users\username>ogrinfo
'ogrinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\username>gdalinfo
Usage: gdalinfo [--help] [--help-general]
                [-json] [-mm] [-stats | -approx_stats] [-hist]
                [-nogcp] [-nomd] [-norat] [-noct] [-nofl]
                [-checksum] [-listmdd] [-mdd <domain>|all]
                [-proj4] [-wkt_format {WKT1|WKT2|<other_format>}]...
                [-sd <subdataset>] [-oo <NAME>=<VALUE>]... [-if <format>]...
                <datasetname>

FAILURE: No datasource specified.


I do not see any folder in the installation folders for the ogr suite of scripts, so I am not sure what happened here. I can provide what folders/files I do see if helpful.
What I installed:
GDAL 3.8.4, released 2024/02/08

https://github.com/cgohlke/win_arm64-wheels is for Arm devices not Intel/AMD.  But I had a look at the main repo https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels and it doesn't include the ogrinfo or ogr2ogr command line binaries either.  It may be a mistake or it may be intentional given that the README notes the "repository provides unofficial binary wheels for some geospatial libraries for Python" so it may be a cut down version with some non-library binaries removed.  If you install from other sources you will get the ogr commandline binaries

Try the GISInternals install for Windows, I've never had a problem with GDAL, OGR, C#, C++ or python libs. https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php

@user2856 thanks for the insights - glad to hear i was seeing the same thing you're describing.

@MichaelStimson thanks for passing along that info - will try that approach instead!
